# adding User control / Page to windows xaml programmatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to switch between my two user controls AddUsers.xaml (user control) and Viewusers.xaml(user Control) programmatically in Window1.xaml (main Window).

I'm trying to switch user controls by Button Event in Window1.xaml.

my Window1. xaml goes like this

```
 <Window x:Class="SwitchUsers.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="400*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" >
    <Button Content="Swithc User Control " Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right"     Margin="0,40,284,0" Name="btnSwittch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="168" />
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
       <!--Here I want to display  two user controls by switching from button on Top -->            
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have two User Controls addUser.xaml  and viewUser.xaml

addUser. xaml  code:

```
 <UserControl x:Class="SwitchUsers.addUser"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
     <Grid>
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,79,0,0"  Name="textBlock1" Text=" Enter Your Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,105,0,0" Name="textBlock2" Text="Enter Your Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,76,0,0" Name="txtBxName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="144,105,0,0" Name="txtBxPassword" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Button Content="Log In" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,160,0,0" Name="btnLogin" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="93" />
    </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

and my second user control  viewUser.xaml

```
  <UserControl x:Class="SwitchUsers.viewUser"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
   <Grid>
    <!--    I hidden  all UI Controls here to keep code short -->    
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First you need to give your stack panel a name

```
<StackPanel Name="myStack"  Grid.Row="1" >
</StackPanel>
```

Then you need something similar to

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private addUser _addUser;
    private viewUser _viewUser;
    private Control _currentUser;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _addUser = new addUser();
        _viewUser = new viewUser();
        _currentUser = _viewUser;
        myStack.Children.Add(_currentUser);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myStack.Children.Clear();
        if (_currentUser == _addUser)
        {
            _currentUser = _viewUser;
        }
        else
        {
            _currentUser = _addUser;
        }
        myStack.Children.Add(_currentUser);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Joun Petrak , i am getting error   withthe above code   Error caption "ArgumentNullExecption was unhandled" & Message is "  Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Children of 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' cannot be null. Object derived from UIElement expected."

Comment: Iam Sorry , it was my mistake while coding .. now its working , can  this affect the perfromace if the usercontrol has many UI controls with loading data from databse ...will applcation hangs ?   .. if so can i use background worker to perform this switch b/w userscontrol

Comment: one more thing ,  now when uer login in usercontrol   adduser.xaml  and when he presses login button (btnLogin in addUser.xaml)  i want to display another user control viewUser.xaml in the window. how can i do this ?

Comment: Are you sure your using the right UI design? I would normally create a UsersView which lists all of the users, and it would have a couple of buttons to create new user button which will show a new window that allow the creation of a user. A edit user button that allows editing of the selected user and a delete user button that shows a are you sure message box before deleting. Once each are complete, you refresh your list. I find MVVM pattern perfect for this sort of thing. But it takes a bit of time to get your head around it.

Comment: it's ok. but  i want to do some more tricks here  ..  when  in the add user.xaml control i have a btnLogin which login the user  and after login i want to display viewuser.xaml  control in addUser.xaml contrlo place .  now for that i belive  i need to access the parent Window ( am i right?) so , how to access the parent windows stock panel which holds this usercontrol >